# ImportError : No Module Named pytesseract

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, libraries, importerror

I have installed `pytesseract` successfully but still getting this error in `vscode`.

I tried installing tesseract in my `venv` in `vscode`. and it was successfully installed. but still , I'm getting this error.

I used a simple code i.e.,

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as pt
def tesseract():
    path_to_tesseract = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
    image_path="test.jpg"
    pt.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract
    text = pt.image_to_string(Image.open(image_path))
    print(text)
tesseract()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found that sometimes just restarting VsCode might fix the import issue

Comment: did that, didn't work for me.

Comment: Show us the Python interpreter you selected inside vs code.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way this `ImportError` can occur is if `pip install` refers to a different Python version than VS Code is using, or the virtual environment is not activated in VS Code, or it was not activated when pytesseract was installed.

You can check that `pip` matches the Python version VS Code is using by running:

```
pip -V
```

at the command line, and remember it's output. Then, in VS Code run the following Python script and make sure they match. If they match, then there shouldn't be an issue. If they don't match, some combinations of the virtual environment and the Python Version are not setup correctly.

```
import sys, subprocess
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "-V"])
```

If this is the issue, it can be solved by installed pytesseract by running the following Python script in VS Code.

```py
import sys, subprocess

subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "pytesseract"])

import pytesseract
```

To explain the command, `subprocess.check_call` executes a call on the command line, as if you had typed it at the terminal. The difference is uses the full path to the Python Interpreter, from `sys.executable` (including the virtual environment) to make sure it is setup right.

If this completes without an `ImportError`, then pytesseract should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Import errors occur either due to the package not being installed or being installed in a different path.

Since you said you installed pytesseract, I’m guessing it’s the latter. Try running your script in verbose mode with the `-v` flag to see the path in which Python looks for your packages.

Then you can manually check if pytesseract is installed inside there or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

While in your venv, can you try running

```
pip3 freeze > installed-modules.txt
```

and share the output here? That should show us what modules are installed in your venv and we can continue from there. Also, do you have the **Python Environment Manager** extension installed in VS Code?

So sorry but last initial troubleshooting step, in the bottom right corner of VS code, when you have your python file open, does it state that it's using the venv? This can be really telling if its just not utilizing your venv

[vs-code demonstration venv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61woU.png)